# pandas-how to apply different function to df.series while the function depending on another series?

Tags: python, pandas

Simply speaking, I want to do this:

```
df.s1.map["a":df.s2+1, "b":df.s2-1]
```

However,it won't work because `df.s2` is not a constant.

How can I map `s1` on `df.s2+1` while `s1='a'`,and map `s1` on `df.s2-1` while `s1='b'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` using `lambda` with `axis = 1` i.e

if you have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'s1':['a','b','a','a','b'],'s2':[1,3,5,2,4]})
df['s3'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['s2']+1 if x['s1'] == 'a'  else x['s2']-1 ,axis=1 )
```

Or take d['s2'] common from the dictionary and then add it at the end after mapping.

```
df['s3'] = df.s1.map({'a':1,'b':-1})+df['s2']
```

Output:

```
   s1  s2  s3
0  a  1   2 
1  b  3   2 
2  a  5   6 
3  a  2   3 
4  b  4   3 
In [364]:
```

Output :